# How to apply Google Text-to-speech in android

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

I've developed an Android application. I want to apply Google text-to-speech instead of default text-to-speech feature in the device into my project.

I've searched but didn't find any example or tutorial about google text-to-speech. How to apply Google text-to-speech in an Android project?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by the user only. Earlier the `Tts` API had a function `setEngineByPackageName()` which allowed the engine to be set. But it has been deprecated in `API 14`. But if you do need to use the `Google Tts Engine`, you can prompt the users to go the `Text-to-Speech settings` and change the engine manually.